# cellForItemAtIndexPath being called beyond bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` which utilizes a custom `UICollectionViewCell` class.  The basic idea is the collection view will traverse directories and display photos contained within the directory (results via API calls).  The initial view controller displays a `UICollectionView`, and taps on the cells generates a new view with a new `UICollectionView`.  The directory contents are stored in an `NSMutableDictionary` with the directory ID being the key.

The problem occurs when a new view/collectionview is created with a rather short list of photos -- usually less than 30.  When I rotate the device, the collection view attempts to re-render, and the app crashes with a "index X beyond bounds [0 .. Y]", with X being a number larger than Y (the last element of the array).

I've noticed this tends to only happen when the newly displayed collection view has less items than the "root" collection view.

Here are examples of the relevant (some of it, anyway) code:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[photos objectForKey:api.directoryID] count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PhotoCell *photoCell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    photoCell.photo = [[photos objectForKey:api.directoryID] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return photoCell;
}
```

At the very least, I'd like to do a try/catch on the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, but don't know where I would put the try/catch.  Perhaps in a custom `UICollectionView`?

Thanks!

Comment: I would start by adding NSLog() statements in `numberOfItemsInSection`  and in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` to check the `directoryID` and the value of `[[photos objectForKey:api.directoryID] count]`.

Comment: Yeah, I already did that.  And also printed the `indexPath.row` for every cell.  It prints the usual, "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc" until the last element, and then tacks on a wildly out of bounds index at the end.

Comment: `NSLog` the `collectionView` in the methods. A setup with more than one `UICollectionView` once has bitten me, since I didn't keep track of the 'correct' collection view and operated on the wrong one (it also gave me 'out of bounds' errors).

Comment: did you try to add an Exception Breakpoint for ALL EXCEPTIONS? if the problem is in your code, it'll pin point the relevant line.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[photos objectForKey:api.directoryID] count];
}
```

I assume, you use one **delegate** and **dataSource** object for all of your `UICollectionView` instances.
If so, rewrite your code in this manner:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view
         numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ( view == _firstCollectionView )
    {
        return [[photos objectForKey:api.directoryID] count];
    }
    else if ( view == _secondCollectionView )
    {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Also you should rewrite `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method in such way.